# How to read first word of every line, into one line in a file

Tags: python, file, split

```
with open("my_file.txt", "r") as f:
     next(f)                         # used to skip the first line in the file
     for line in f:
         words = line.split()        
         if words:
            print(words[0])
```

Will output:

```
a-1,
b-2,
c-3,
```

I want it to output/read this from the file:

```
a-1, b-2, c-3,
```

Comment: `print(words[0], end=','`

Comment: @Chris_Rands - It looks to me like the comma is already in the word, and what's needed is a space. `print(words[0], end=' ')`.

Comment: you can put all words on list and later convert them to one string using `" ".join(list)` and print it

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the words into a list then join them on spaces:

```
with open("my_file.txt", "r") as f:
    first_words = []
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        if words:
            first_words.append(words[0])
    
print(' '.join(first_words))
```

Output:

```
a-1, b-2, c-3,
```